# Graphical code analysis

Tags: svn, hudson, visualization, code-analysis

I'm using SubVersion in conjunction with Hudson, and I like the feature that shows the how the unit tests, build time, disk usage grow over time. I'm a believer in code metrics to get a first cut appraisal of a code base - especially useful when starting with a new client. Are there any tools that can do the following

1) Starting from Date/Tag get every revision of the Source Code

2) Build it

3) Run code analysis

4) Run tests

5) Store detailed results (in Sql database of somekind)

6) Repeat until no more revisions

7) Collate and present the results

You can see a [summary output](http://fisheye4.atlassian.com/browse/hudson) for hudson itself, but that gives no idea of individual files, and how they have changed over time.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Sonar https://www.sonarqube.org/. I have used this using maven for my Java project. It reports most of the features you looking for.

Comment: Hi, Your link is dead. Could you update it for future readers?